# Sweave Cache packages

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

I am trying to sweave a report and my problem is that every time i compile R loads the packages I use in the Report (like ggplot2, MASS, cubature..). This is very time consuming. Is there a way to chache the packages?

I found *cacheSweave* but it does not work.

This is the chunk i added in the sweave file:

```
<<cacheSweave, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, term=FALSE, cache=TRUE>>=
library(cacheSweave) 
 lapply(c("ghyp","MASS","nloptr","cubature","ggplot2"), require, character.only=T)
@
```

Thanks

Comment: loading packages is what `cachSweave` called "side effects", which cannot be cached; if you use `knitr`, I can point you a direction to go

Comment: I didn't know *knitr*, it looks interessting. Maybe I'll try it this weekend! How would you do it with knitr? Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you showed interest in the `knitr` package, I spent some time implementing this feature, and you can download the development version from https://github.com/yihui/knitr. As I said, `cacheSweave` does not preserve any side effects; the current stable version of `knitr` on CRAN only preserves the side effects of printing, and the side effects of loading packages are preserved in the development version (>= 0.3.3) on GitHub. When you run a cached chunk, all the package names are cached in a file `__packages`. Next time when this chunk is to be rebuilt, all the packages will be loaded before executing the code in the chunk, otherwise this chunk will be skipped. In other words, packages are only loaded when they are really needed.

The other way to do this is to use chunk hooks, which does not require you to install the development version. For example, you can add a chunk option named `packages`, and design a chunk hook like:

```
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
knit_hooks$set(packages = function(before, options, envir) {
  if (before) {
    ## load packages before a chunk is executed
    for (p in options$packages) library(p, character.only = TRUE)
  }
})
@
```

Then you can use this chunk option like

```
<<test, packages=c('MASS', 'ggplot2')>>=
qplot(rnorm(100))
@
```

where the option `packages` is a character vector of package names, which are used by the chunk hook defined above. The disadvantage of this approach is you may have to specify this `packages` vector for many chunks, whereas the first approach is automatic. You may need to spend a few minutes on learning how chunk hooks work in `knitr`: http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks

Answer (score 1):

You don't call `library(cacheSweave)` in your Sweave (rnw) file. Consider the following `test.rnw` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
<<cachedCode,cache=TRUE>>=
#this Sweave block will be cached
@
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Then you would run this using:

```
require(cacheSweave)
Sweave('test.rnw', driver=cacheSweaveDriver)
```

Comment: your statement is true but doesn't answer the OP's question (see @Yihui's comment above)