# what does it mean that "cacheSweave doesn't cache side-effects"?

Tags: r, caching, sweave, chunks

I'm using cachesweave, but I don't think I get how everything works. I've tried to separate the code  into  simulation chunks and the plotting chunks, but some of the code is very long and written before I started the sweave document, so I instead use something like

```
 <<foo,cache=TRUE>>
 source("mainScript.R")
 @
 <<plot,fig=TRUE>>
 a<- print(str(F1))
 plot(F1)
 @
```

The thing is mainScript.R is somewhat convoluted simulation code including plot functions and so on. I've read in cacheSweave vignette "cacheSweave doesn't cache side-effects" and plots are not cached, so I was wondering if the plotting functions in mainScript.R effect how the expressions are evaluated?

This might be an obvious question. Let's say I have another chunk after the two above. all of the results of the expressions in both "foo" and "plot" can be used in this new chunk, right? For example,

```
 <<post-chunk>>
 print(a)
 print(str(F1))
 @
```

Comment: Just as an aside - you might want to look into knitr.  It's basically a much nicer version of Sweave that has caching built in automatically and does cache plots.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538367/sweave-cache-packages/9561953#9561953

Answer (score 3):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) for a full explanation. Some common side-effects in R include: `print()` objects, draw plots, write files and load packages.

The `cacheSweave` package only enables you to skip computation, and you have to lose all side-effects. As Dason commented, the [`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/) package is much more natural in terms of caching -- what you see in an uncached chunk will be seen in the cached chunk. The caching of side-effects in `knitr` is explained in [its manual](https://github.com/downloads/yihui/knitr/knitr-manual.pdf) and the [cache page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/) in the website.

BTW, `knitr` keeps compatibility with Sweave and cacheSweave, so hopefully you do not need to do anything for the transition; just call `library(knitr); knit('file.Rnw')`.

Comment: thank you. I was trying out knitr, but I'm new to sweave and didn't want to dive into another tool before I fully understood how weaving and caching  works. So what is happening is once a chunk is cached, all packages loaded will not be available and plots drawn and output printed, will not be output the next time the document is weaved.